# Algorithmics issue, python string, no idea

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have algorithm problem with Python and strings.

My issue:

My function should sum maximum values of substring. 
For example:

```
ae-afi-re-fi -> 2+6+3+5=16
but 
ae-a-fi-re-fi -> 2-10+5+3+5=5
```

I try use string.count function and counting substring, but this method is not good. 
What would be the best way to do this in Python? Thanks in advance.

```
string = "aeafirefi"
```

Sum the value of substrings.

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: Dynamic programming.

Comment: I have only problem with type this algorithm. My idea is not correct. The string is input by user. My string is example.

Comment: yes, but we cannot advise you if we don't know what the implementation of your algorithm is. we need to see your code

Comment: I think that the main problem in your question is how to escape from counting `qd` and `qdd` twice also for `fi`, `afi` and `fir`.

Comment: Yes, It's a true. I don't have any idea.

Comment: i've made a solution wich work only for `aeafirefi` but give wrong result for `aeafirefiqdd`. Maybe it can be a start for you

Comment: My analyzed string must be between "ae" and "fi" string = "doesnotmatteraesomethingfidoes..."

Comment: wait, i'm trying to find a solution this problem. By the way it's a good question.

Comment: I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my solution i'll use `permutations` from `itertools` module in order to list all the possible permutations of substrings that you gave in your question presented into a dict called `vals`. Then iterate through the input string and split the strings by all the permutations found below. Then sum the values of each permutations and finally get the max.

**PS:** The key of this solution is the `get_sublists()` method.

This is an example with some tests:

```
from itertools import permutations 

def get_sublists(a, perm_vals):
    # Find the sublists in the input string
    # Based on the permutations of the dict vals.keys()
    for k in perm_vals:
        if k in a:
            a = ''.join(a.split(k))
            # Yield the sublist if we found any
            yield k

def sum_sublists(a, sub, vals):
    # Join the sublist and compare it to the input string
    # Get the difference by lenght
    diff = len(a) - len(''.join(sub))
    # Sum the value of each sublist (on every permutation)
    return sub , sum(vals[k] for k in sub) - diff * 10

def get_max_sum_sublists(a, vals):
    # Get all the possible permutations
    perm_vals = permutations(vals.keys())
    # Remove duplicates if there is any
    sub = set(tuple(get_sublists(a, k)) for k in perm_vals)
    # Get the sum of each possible permutation
    aa = (sum_sublists(a, k, vals) for k in sub)
    # return the max of the above operation
    return max(aa, key= lambda x: x[1])


vals = {'ae': 2, 'qd': 3, 'qdd': 5, 'fir': 4, 'afi': 6, 're': 3, 'fi': 5}

# Test
a = "aeafirefi"
final, s = get_max_sum_sublists(a, vals)
print("Sublists: {}\nSum: {}".format(final, s))
print('----')
a = "aeafirefiqdd"
final, s = get_max_sum_sublists(a, vals)
print("Sublists: {}\nSum: {}".format(final, s))
print('----')
a = "aeafirefiqddks"
final, s = get_max_sum_sublists(a, vals)
print("Sublists: {}\nSum: {}".format(final, s))
```

Output:

```
Sublists: ('ae', 'afi', 're', 'fi')
Sum: 16
----
Sublists: ('afi', 'ae', 'qdd', 're', 'fi')
Sum: 21
----
Sublists: ('afi', 'ae', 'qdd', 're', 'fi')
Sum: 1
```

Please try this solution with many input strings as you can and don't hesitate to comment if you found any wrong result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and comments! Maybe someone will find a new, other idea for my issue.

Comment: Test it with many inputs as you can. I think it can solve any input, but who knows ... Don't forget to accept the best answer that fills your needs. Have fun.

Comment: @WaterInButtle I tested this solution and it works fine. Try it in your box

Answer (score 0):

Probably having a dictionary with: 
key = substring: value = value

So if you have:
string = "aeafirefi"

first you look for the whole string in the dictionary, if you don't find it, you cut the last letter so you have "aeafiref", until you find a substring or you have an only letter.

then you skip the letters used: for example, if you found "aeaf", you start all over again using string = "iref".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force solution:

```
values_dict = {
    'ae': 2,
    'qd': 3,
    'qdd': 5,
    'fir': 4,
    'afi': 6,
    're': 3,
    'fi': 5
}

def get_value(x):
    return values_dict[x] if x in values_dict else -10

def next_tokens(s):
    """Returns possible tokens"""
    # Return any tokens in values_dict
    for x in values_dict.keys():
        if s.startswith(x):
            yield x

    # Return single character.
    yield s[0]

def permute(s, stack=[]):
    """Returns all possible variations"""

    if len(s) == 0:
        yield stack
        return

    for token in next_tokens(s):
        perms = permute(s[len(token):], stack + [token])
        for perm in perms:
            yield perm

def process_string(s):
    def process_tokens(tokens):
        return sum(map(get_value, tokens))

    return max(map(process_tokens, permute(s)))

print('Max: {}'.format(process_string('aeafirefi')))
```

Comment: but I need a maximum sum of values. " think that the main problem in your question is how to escape from counting qd and qdd twice also for fi, afi and fir"

Comment: @WaterInButtle I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I get 16 and 5 just like you wrote in your question.

Comment: @WaterInButtle Done!

Comment: @Matten Thanks a lot for help and your time!

Comment: @Matten, can you show me how looks your code without map() ?
 return max(map(process_tokens, permute(s)))

Comment: map can be replaced with `(process_tokens(x) for x in permute(s))`. See "generator expressions". **Alternatively**, you can also use a for loop which computes `process_tokens` on each element of `permute(s)` and chooses the maximum.

Comment: What means: perms = permute(s[len(token):], stack + [token]) and "colon" operator : -> len(token) -> : <- ?

Comment: That's called index slicing. It takes a slice of everything from `s[len(token)]` to the very end of the string.